# AWS CodeCommit integration with Bitrise with periodic ssh key rotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, bitrise

I need to integrate Bitrise with AWS CodeCommit, but also I should rotate ssh key periodically for more security.

As I understand integration possible only through ssh key as it is described in the guide:
https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/integrating-aws-codecommit-with-bitrise/158

In Bitrise I should have the following settings:
[image]

In AWS IAM:
[image]

If I will rotate ssh key in aws I only can delete old one and upload new one but it will create a new ‘SSH key ID’(I do not see any functionality to update current ssh key to save ‘SSH key ID’ the same)

Bitrise has api to update ssh https://api-docs.bitrise.io/#/app-setup/ssh-key-create but there is no any api to update ‘REPOSITORY URL’

Is there another way how to deal with rotation ssh key to save integration AWS CodeCommit and Bitrise?